# upload base64 image to cloudinary in angular2

Tags: angular, base64, image-uploading, cloudinary

How to upload `base64 image` on `cloudinary`  in `angular2`?

**ex:I have one variable which stores base64 uri of image. I want to upload that image on cloudinary. How can i do that in angular2?**

Comment: Improved content formatting and added relevant tag

Comment: What have you done so far? Post more specific question.